# Android HAL tag: HARDWARE_MODULE_TAG & HARDWARE_DEVICE_TAG

Tags: android

Does anybody know why tag in struct hw_module_t must be initialized to HARDWARE_MODULE_TAG and tag in struct hw_device_t must be initialized to HARDWARE_DEVICE_TAG ? I grep the code base under /hardware/libhardware/ and some other for hal stubs but there's no reference to both tags.
So, do both tags really have functionality?